# Default value when using multiple inputs

Tags: python, user-input

How can i set default values on the w, d & h?

```
w, d, h = input("Specify width, depth & height: ").split()
print (w)
print (d)
print (h)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Explicit is better than implicit*:

```
values = input("Specify width, depth & height: ").split()

w = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else DEFAULT_W
d = values[1] if len(values) > 1 else DEFAULT_D
h = values[2] if len(values) > 2 else DEFAULT_H
```

But a more extravagant way could be:

```
values = iter(input("Specify width, depth & height: ").split())

w = next(values, DEFAULT_W)
d = next(values, DEFAULT_D)
h = next(values, DEFAULT_H)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
w, d, h = input("Specify width, depth & height: ").split() or (10, 11, 12)
print (w)
print (d)
print (h)
```

This sets the values to a default if the user entered nothing, since an empty string will be split to an empty list, which will be evaluated to `False`.

Comment: Simple and sweet. +1

Comment: But will fail if the user enters one or two. But I guess it might be the OP's intention. It's not very clear from the question.

Comment: Also, using `or (...)` with a tuple of default values would be more logical, to avoid an unnecessary split of your default values. (and empty list after split would also evaluate to `False`

Comment: Yes, it is worth noting that it will also fail if the user enters something nonsensical, like letters. Validation is a whole different task

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych +1 You're right, that's better! Didn't think about an empty list also evaluating to false.